# how to Elfinderk img show

Tags: yii2, widget, show, elfinder

I'm using the Elfinderk widget, I need to see what the image looks like without clicking on it, so wher[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7173.png)e should I change the widget setting. thank you what solution do you give?

I using code